# MySQL data in listview gets looped (?)

Tags: vb.net

I have my listview went wrong today, the data inside looped endlessly. What's wrong?

```
  Public Sub list1()
    SQLs = "SELECT * FROM petugas"
    Using CMD As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(SQLs, conn)
        DR = CMD.ExecuteReader
        While DR.Read
            With ListPetugas
                .Items.Add(DR("kd_petugas")).ToString()
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(DR("nm_petugas").ToString())
                    .Add(DR("j_kel_petugas").ToString())
                    .Add(DR("almt_petugas").ToString())
                    .Add(DR("tlp_petugas").ToString())
                End With
            End With
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I known hardly anything about .NET but within VB6 you need to move the cursor after having read a row (.MoveNext).

Comment: Errr... this is vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you dumping DR to ListPetugas?

What context is ListPetugas?

Please show us the event that is calling this sub.

You should use dt instead if you are actually holding all the data in an object.